# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winterbash, hats

After reading [a meta post on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8336/145596) about opting-out of Winterbash 2016, I figured I'd ask the community here.  This will be our first chance to participate in Winterbash, but it is an opt-out program.  The mods would just need to let the CM team know by December 13th.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I want hats and think it's a great idea for our site to participate.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is true that this year's Winterbash will run from 19 December to 8 January.

We at Retrocomputing could opt out as a site.

There is also another way.  Any individual who wishes to opt out will be able to do so.  There will be an *"I hate hats"* button on the site.  You will then not be awarded hats and will not see the hats of others.

My personal view is that Winterbash is a bit of fun, let's do it.  There is always a hat for visiting a new site, so it could attract more people here.

For those who don't know, Winterbash is series of challenges set to the users of StackExchange at the end of the year.  Each challenge successfully completed earns the user a hat.  Some of the challenges are easy, some difficult and a few are secret!   -- And, no, the moderators don't know what the hats are before the start.

Comment: The other site I moderate does the bash every year and it is actually quite fun (surprisingly!). It also helps keep people busy over the typically quiet period.

Answer (score -4):

Let's not do Winter Bash. Our site is still young and it might cause visitors to think that were a really unprofessional site, blah blah, I hate fun.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I disagree with this option. If you want to improve this post by all means do so!

Comment: But you *hat* fun!

Comment: This is a good way to get the peer pressure badge on meta :)

Comment: @JAL I made it Community Wiki; I'm not sure whether that would entitle me to the badge. Besides, I don't plan to delete this answer!