# Should we wear hats this winter?

Tags: discussion, winterbash, hats

Hats are traditionally worn to stay warm by user's profile pictures during an event known as Winter Bash. During this time, the weather in the Northern Hemisphere (where the Stack Exchange servers are housed) drops sharply; this causes some user profile pictures to feel a bit chilly.

Of course, the profile pictures are polite, so will remove their hats when visitors indicate their desire not to see them by clicking the <kbd>I hate hats</kbd> button. We do, however, have the option to make our site a completely hat-free zone for everyone.

[Do we want hats?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/355/278)

Comment: As per tradition, we offer an "I hate hats" option for people who don't want to participate individually. So this question is whether the Retrocomputing Stack Exchange community should offer hats to users. There'd be no way to opt in if the site doesn't have hats at all.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes.

It is very important for user profile pictures to stay warm this winter, especially in the air-conditioned server room.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

Let them freeze. Mwahahahaha! I *hate* fun, and will impose professionalism on *everyone* at *all times*.

Comment: Retrocomputing as such is fun enough - Don't know if I can stand the additional fun introduced by silly hats ;)

Comment: @tofro Tough. We've already started! :-)